# VSE 2012 for Web Error: The data provider required to connect to the local data file could not be found

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I am getting the following error when I am trying to add SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database in the Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web:

> The data provider required to connect to the local data file could not be found. The file will be added to the project but the typed DataSet associated with the file will not be generated.`

I tried reinstalling the CompactDB and I installed the Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU.

Please note: I have Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop and everything there works fine. I can add SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database item.

OS: Windows 7 SP1 Home Premium x64.

Would you be so kind how to fix it?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Thank you for the advise, Tevo! Eventually we had to repair the install and it fixed the issue. But it was interesting if something could have done by manually correcting it.

Anyway, the repair fixed it. Thank you very much for your help, Tevo!

P.S. Don't know how to mark the question answered. May be you may mark it on my behalf.

Answer (score 0):

Fix by repairing the VS installation